# SCNParticleSystem subclass with custom property causes crash

Tags: macos, exc-bad-access, scenekit

If I subclass `SCNParticleSystem` and add a property to the custom subclass, and assign a value to the property. `SceneKit` will crash on Mac. But it works on iOS and tvOS!
The crash always occurs when the particle systems emitter shape is being assigned a `SCNNode` geometry!

Its that: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1...)

See the screenshots & test my simple example project.

I don’t understand why this is crashing, is there a workaround? How can I add custom properties to a SCNParticleSystem otherwise?

Xcode 7.2

Xcode 7.3 beta (7D111g)

Mac OS X 10.11.3 (15D21)

[Example Project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6979623/SCNParticleSystemSubclassBug/SCNParticleSystemSubclassBug.zip)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Radar that puppy! https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Did that too :-) I will reply here when I get a response.

Comment: I'm back, it is the future now…but guess what…still no reply from crApple.